# How are "as of" and "as on" used in these definitions for "on"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand that the meaning of the phrase “as of” is time related, e.g.: [takes effect as of July 1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20of).

But while looking up [***on*** in Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on?showCookiePolicy=true), I found a use of "as of" that didn't make sense to me.  In #13, it says: “**as of** a statement or action”.

The same situation I found in #20: ”**as of** a mechanical operation”.

In #28 I found a similar phrase: ”**as on** stage”.

I have trouble in understanding these three definitions, so would you please explain their meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused between *as of* whole as a preposition and *as* and *of* as two separate words!

> [as of (preposition)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=as%20of) - from that time

Now...

> used to indicate the basis, grounds, or cause, as [of a statement or action] - *of* here means *about* that statement/action.

*As of (something)* can also mean someone's something in that context/condition.

The example of other ***as of***...

> For I heard a cry **as of a woman** in labor, The anguish **as of one giving birth** to her first child, The cry of the daughter of Zion gasping for breath, Stretching out her hands, saying, "Ah, woe is me, for I faint before murderers - [Jeremiah 4:31 (Bible)](http://biblehub.com/jeremiah/4-31.htm)

Comment: Yes, you’ve got my confusion!

Comment: @LucianSava I understand you well then ;)

Answer (score 2):

"as of" you can read as a short form of:

"as we would say about the following".

That meaning is certainly not time-related; "of" here means "about".

If we look, for instance at you #20: (Keeping in mind we are talking about the adverb **on** here!)

> in the position or state required for the commencement or sustained continuation, as of a mechanical operation   ⇒ the radio's been on all night

Dictionaries leave out a lot of text because it would become very repetitive. The full explanation here would read:

> "on", as an adverb, can also mean "in the position or state required for the commencement or sustained continuation", as we could say about a mechanical operation   ⇒ the radio's been **on** all night (meaning, the radio has been is a state required for sustained continuation of the radio's function).

As for #28:

> performing, as on stage   ⇒ I'm on in five minutes
>
> "on", as an adjective, can be used to mean "performing", as people do on a stage   ⇒ I'm on in five minutes, meaning I will be performing on stage in five minutes.